# Difference between two proportions belonging to the same sample?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

$500$ people are surveyed and $6\%$ said they want full protection of alligators, $16\%$ said they want their complete destruction, $52\%$ said they want them to be relocated, and finally, $26\%$ said they want the alligators to be harvested. Is there a difference between the proportion of people who want alligators to be protected and those who want alligators to be destroyed? Use $\alpha$ = 0.01.

How do I find if there is a difference using R?

I don't think this will work with a two-sample proportion test, so I'm really stuck on this question.

Comment: $(6\%+16\%+56\%+26\%)>100\%$. So respondents can provide $>1$ answer?

Comment: @StatsPlease Oh, I'm sorry, $56\%$ is supposed to be $52\%$. OK. I just edited the question.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Can you provide the context for this question? Where did it come from? It strikes me as unusual & not well formed, but if it came from a textbook (eg) the chapter might have information about how they want it answered.

Answer (score 1):

**This one is a little tricky because the responses are not independent** (attested by the fact they sum to unity).  One way to approach it (out of many) is to "condition on" the responses of interest; namely, the 6% favoring protection and the 16% favoring destruction.

We can't learn enough from the percentages alone because they don't reveal how much variation could have occurred.  **Begin, then, by translating percentages into counts.**  This is a little uncertain because the percentages have been given only to one significant figure.  I will therefore interpret "6%" as meaning "somewhere between 5.5% and 6.5%" and likewise for "16%."  Thus,

- Since 5.5% of 500 (rounded towards 6%) is 28 and 6.5% of 500 (rounded towards 6%) is 32, "6%" means "between 28 and 32 inclusive."
- Similarly, "16%" means "between 78 and 82 inclusive."

You can compute these values in `R` using standard arithmetic operations, as in this implementation:

```
r <- function(percentage, total) {
    start <- ceiling((percentage - 1/2)/100 * total)
    end <- floor((percentage + 1/2)/100 * total)
    i <- start:end
    names(i) <- i
    i
}
```

For instance, `r(6, 500)` produces the sequence of numbers from 28 through 32.

These cases, which cover five possible values each, thereby comprise 25 different possible results.  Let us discuss them a little generally in order to develop a formula for the answer: let $k$ be the number favoring protection and $m$ the number favoring destruction.  **According to the null hypothesis, these are random responses out of a sample of $k+m$ subjects coming from a population in which half the people favor protection and the other half favor destruction.**  The response by the protectionists (let's call it $X$) therefore has a Binomial distribution with parameters $k+m$ and $1/2.$

**Before proceeding we ought to do few quick checks to get a sense of what the answer will be.** These can be performed mentally, they are so simple.  Note that this Binomial distribution has a mean of $(k+m)/2,$ which will be halfway between 6% and 16% of $500$ and therefore is close to $55,$ and a variance close to $110(1/2)(1-1/2) = 110/4.$  The standard deviation is the square root of that, or around $10.5/2 \approx 5.3.$  The observed value of $X,$ which lies near $30,$ therefore is approximately $(55-30)/5.3$ standard deviations from the mean.  That's somewhere between $25/6\approx 4$ and $25/5=5$ SDs.  Since a Binomial distribution with these parameters will be approximately Normal, and we know that Normal distributions rarely exhibit values more than $3$ SDs beyond the mean, **we immediately conclude the observations are strongly inconsistent with the null hypothesis.**

---

**If you want to be more formal,** you can proceed in various ways.  One solution is to adopt a symmetric two-sided test, where the p-value is the sum of two chances: (1) the chance that $X$ is less than or equal to $k$ and (2) the chance that $X$ is greater than or equal to $m.$  These chances are computed by the `R` function `pbinom`.  You might implement it like this:

```
p <- function(k, m) pbinom(k, m+k, 1/2) + pbinom(m+1, m+k, 1/2, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

In one stroke you can explore all 25 possible p-values using the generalized outer product:

```
print(outer(r(6, 500), r(16, 500), p), digits=2)
```

> ```
>         78      79      80      81      82
> 28 7.0e-07 4.7e-07 3.1e-07 2.1e-07 1.4e-07
> 29 1.3e-06 8.9e-07 6.0e-07 4.1e-07 2.7e-07
> 30 2.4e-06 1.7e-06 1.1e-06 7.7e-07 5.2e-07
> 31 4.4e-06 3.0e-06 2.1e-06 1.4e-06 9.8e-07
> 32 7.8e-06 5.4e-06 3.7e-06 2.6e-06 1.8e-06
> ```

The value offering the least evidence against the null hypothesis is the largest of these, equal to $7.8 \times 10^{-6}$ when $k=32$ and $m=78$ (shown at the bottom left corner of the matrix).  Since this is less than $\alpha=0.01,$ **the difference is significant.**

---

BTW, the considerations of rounding sometimes are important.  Suppose the reported responses had been 8% and 14% rather than 6% and 16%, for instance.  Repeating the calculations with these values gives a range of possible p-values from $0.00095$ to $0.0111$: some of them are significant at the 1% level and some are not.  In this case, the imprecision in reporting the statistics makes the decision indeterminate!