# Comparing two samples based on only their percentiles

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

I have some statistics for two samples from a population:

```
Sample size, Percent relative standard error (PRSE), mean,
percentile 10, percentile 25, median, percentile 75 and percentile 90
```

I've no other information. Is there any statistical test that I can tell the distribution of these two samples are significantly different or similar?

Comment: Can't you get standard deviation?

Comment: With no other information, and assuming the sample sizes are 10 or larger, the mean doesn't give you useful information for this test.  With sample sizes 20 or larger, the standard deviation won't help, either (cc @AdamO).  My answer to the related (but simpler) question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/390495/919 shows one way to proceed.

Comment: It depends on your purposes, but practically speaking, if all of those statistics are relatively similar, the distributions are likely similar.  That's probably the best you can do.

Comment: @AdamO I actually have Percent relative standard error (PRSE). I added it to the post.

Comment: It's likely these numbers are all positive, for otherwise PRSE usually isn't meaningful.  Are you *sure* you don't have even more information about the samples?  Would there be a definite upper bound for all the values, for instance?

Comment: @SalMangiafico what test you suggest for comparing the percentiles?

Comment: @whuber No, that's all I have. Btw, the sample sizes are big, Say few thousands.

Comment: @HosseinAyouqi, I don't know of any test you can use.  Just an informal conclusion.

Comment: With sample sizes that large, conducting five independent tests of each percentile and adjusting for multiple testing, under the incorrect but fairly accurate assumption of independence, would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If the distributions are assumed to be continuous, one idea is to interpolate between the percentiles to estimate the KS test statistic.

In R:

```
set.seed(1719668601)
n1 <- 3e3L
n2 <- 2e3L
a <- rnorm(n1)
b <- rnorm(n2, 0, 1.05) # slightly different distribution
p1 <- c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9)
p2 <- c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9)
x1 <- quantile(a, p1)
x2 <- quantile(b, p2)
x12 <- sort(c(x1, x2))
```

Interpolating between the percentiles shows that the estimated test statistic occurs at -0.63718241 (`x1[2]`), where the vertical distance between the two lines is maximized:

```
approxfun(x2, p2, rule = 2)(x1[2]) - 0.25
#> [1] 0.04077355
plot(x1, p1, col = "purple", type = "l")
lines(x2, p2, col = "red")
```

[image]

The test statistic is $D\sqrt{\frac{n_1\cdot{}n_2}{n_1+n_2}}$, where $D$ is the maximum vertical distance between the two interpolated lines.

```
1 - .Call(stats:::C_pKS2,
          sqrt(n1 * n2/(n1 + n2))*max(abs(approxfun(x1, p1, rule = 2)(x12) - approxfun(x2, p2, rule = 2)(x12)), na.rm = TRUE),
          1e-6)
#> [1] 0.03700076
```

Compare the result to a KS test using the underlying data rather than the percentiles.

```
ks.test(a, b)$p.value
#> [1] 0.02620369
```

Based on Monte-Carlo simulation, this approach will be rather conservative for many distributions.

Illustrating using the distribution of p-values when the distributions are the same (again, using random normals):

```
ftest <- function(n1, p1, n2, p2, f1, f2) {
  x12 <- sort(c(x1 <- quantile(f1(n1), p1), x2 <- quantile(f2(n2), p2)))
  
  1 - .Call(stats:::C_pKS2,
            sqrt(n1 * n2/(n1 + n2))*max(abs(approxfun(x1, p1, rule = 2)(x12) - approxfun(x2, p2, rule = 2)(x12)), na.rm = TRUE),
            1e-6)
}

s <- replicate(1e4, ftest(sample(1e3:5e3, 1), p1, sample(1e3:5e3, 1), p2, rnorm, rnorm))
plot(ecdf(s), col = "blue")
lines(c(0, 1), c(0, 1))
```

[image]

The p-values are distributed higher than those we would expect by using the true test statistic.

The behavior is similar when the distributions are slightly different as in the first example:

```
s1 <- replicate(1e4, ftest(sample(1e3:5e3, 1), p1, sample(1e3:5e3, 1), p2, rnorm, function(n) rnorm(n, 0, 1.05)))
s2 <- replicate(1e4, ks.test(rnorm(sample(1e3:5e3, 1)), rnorm(sample(1e3:5e3, 1), 0, 1.05))$p.value)
plot(ecdf(s1), col = "blue")
plot(ecdf(s2), add = TRUE, col = "orange")
lines(c(0, 1), c(0, 1))
```

[image]

This pattern holds for multiple continuous distributions that I've tried (normal, uniform, exponential, beta, gamma). A significant p-value using the estimate of the KS statistic generally requires the difference between the distributions to be more pronounced than if using the actual KS statistic.

Comment: You can't trust the KS p value unless you're willing to assume at least one distribution is continuous.

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot to add that as an assumption.

Comment: I also wonder how you are treating the tails.  In the example, *nothing* is known about the upper and lower 10% of each distribution apart from the bounds afforded by the 10th and 90th percentiles.  Thus, potentially, both distributions can be continuous yet the KS statistic could exceed 0.1 on this basis alone.  Because the sample sizes are large, this makes it certain that the KS test will reject the null hypothesis unless you add strong assumptions about tail behaviors.

Comment: The tails aren't used. I added more explanation. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @jblood94 Thanks a lot. Can you please add a conclusion at the end? I got kind of lost.

Comment: Yes, that was ending rather abruptly. I gave it a try.